# https markdown links don't work in README.md

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I was trying to insert a markdown link in a README.md file (in particular, the README.md file of the special repository whose name is the same as my Github profile), on Github.
Although I've done this for other repositories before, it doesn't work this time.

You can see on [README.md file](https://github.com/lorenzobunaj/lorenzobunaj/blob/main/README.md) how it actually appears.
At first, I thought that this was normal since the README is in the special repository, however, I saw that many people are able to insert markdown links in their special repository README, so I don't know what the problem might be caused by.

Comment: You want to insert a markdown file link in your readme.md file, if it is correct then which file link you want to add? And there is not any md file link in this [readme file](https://github.com/lorenzobunaj/lorenzobunaj/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: in this file [readme file](https://github.com/lorenzobunaj/lorenzobunaj/blob/main/README.md) ever link working fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply substituting `<br>` with `</br>`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).